# only show running services using service --status-all and grep

Tags: linux, grep

If I do `service --status-all` I get something like this:

```
[ ? ]  webmin
[ ? ]  whoopsie
[ + ]  winbind
[ - ]  x11-common
```

I want to show just the running ones ([ + ]) so I did

```
service --status-all | grep +
```

which highlights them, but how do I make it exclude the other lines?

Also, is this showing actual running services or just ones which are scheduled to run at startup?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the amount of surrounding lines `grep` outputs (called the "context") with options `-C [num]` or `--context=[num]`.

Usually, the default option for `grep` is to print no context, so the command you used should be fine. You can force it to show only matching lines by `service --status-all | grep + -C 0`.

To exclude matching lines, use `-v` or `--invert-match`. So, you can pipe the original command through `| grep -v '[ ?' | grep -v '[ -'` to get rid of lines with `-` or `?` as their status. You can also combine multiple match strings by using escaped "or" (the pipe symbol), like `grep -v '[ ?\|[ -'`.

However, as `service` for some reason directs its output to `stderr` instead of the normal `stdout`, the output streams need to be combined with `|&` for the `grep` to work properly. So, the working command here would be `service --status-all |& grep +`.

Comment: `service --status-all | grep + -C 0` does exactly the same thing.
Using `grep -v` also doesn't work.

However, this works:
`    service --status-all > services.txt
     cat services.txt | grep +`

Comment: Ok, `service` behaves erratically, please see the last paragraph of the edited answer.